# What is mean by Device is asleep

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have read the android document for AlarmManager. In that they mentioned like

> "Registered alarms are retained while the device is asleep (and can
>   optionally wake the device up if they go off during that time), but
>   will be cleared if it is turned off and rebooted".

How can i know, My Device is asleep. If my device Screen is Off or If it is locked , Can i consider My Device is asleep?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118007/what-is-the-definition-of-asleep-for-an-android-device

Answer (score 0):

It depends. On my Samsung Galaxy S4 it gets locked if device sleeps (Screen lights off) and I have to swipe to open it. On my Nexus 4 after it sleeps on pressing lock button it directly wakes up (no swiping required)